# view machine learning model derived in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, scale

I have a general question, I guess it is common to many Spark ML users, but I searched over the internet, and didn't find an answer.

Let's say if I use one of the estimators from Spark ML package to fit a data set with a model. How can view the model? For example the model is a decision tree, how can I view the actual tree? All the nodes, splits, etc.

Thanks,
-Fan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a decision tree:

`tree_model.toDebugString()`

Not all algorithms have visual components, and even some that may have visual components do not necessarily have that aspect implemented in Spark.

Comment: got it! Thank youI

Comment: It's polite to 'Accept' the answer if it successfully answered your question :-)

Comment: Yes, I accepted it.  I am a new user, so my vote won't display immediately